# include header files in cmake

Tags: include, cmake

I have a CMakeList.txt file which has just one liner
`include(startevn.cmake)`
in startevn.cmake I have,

```
project(startevn)
set(headers 
   startup.h
)
set(sources
  system-init.cpp
)
new_library(startevn ${sources} ${headers})
```

Now I have to move the startup to a different directory. After doing that I added
the following line to "startevn.cmake",

```
include_directories("/new_folder_location/sub_folder")
```

where sub_folder is where startup.h is now located but compiler still says
Cannot find source file: startup.h.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you really mean "/new_folder_location/sub_folder"?  That's an absolute path.  To give a relative path, remove the leading "/".

Comment: yes, it is an absolute path.

Comment: Should work then.  Have you tried running `make VERBOSE=1` to see the actual compiler commands?  You should have something like `-I/new_folder_location/sub_folder` in there.

Answer (score 3):

cause the code before:

`new_library(startevn ${sources} ${headers})`

it did tell the library's location,

but after, your `include_directories()` maybe isn't.

try：

```
set(INCLUDE_DIR /new_folder_location/sub_folder)
include_directories (${INCLUDE_DIR})     # make sure your .h all inside.
```

(or need to use  find_library() of cmake before to check if it is rightly found.)